# url rewriting for dynamic pages

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

I have implemented the URL rewriting in mu php web site

Here I need to display my link as

```
mydomain.com/komet-india/Best-Indian-Hill-Stations-1/Delhis-Hotel
```

Here `Best-Indian-Hill-Stations,1,Delhis-Hotel` are dynamic value 
I will give another example too

```
mydomain.com/komet-india/Popular Indian Pilgrimages-2/new-Hotel
```

Here

```
Popular Indian Pilgrimages,2,new-Hotel
```

Are dynamic values.

First parameter is the category, second is the id and the third is the name of a hotel

I have write the following url to do this see my code

```
Rewrite Rule (\d+)-(\d+)/(.*)/? hotel-detail.php?title=$1&id=$2&top=$3&hotel=4 [nc]
```

But it's result in NOT found page

Does anyone give me a solution?

Comment: `Rewrite Rule` -> `RewriteRule`

Comment: I would just dispatch every page (except for static resources such as CSS, images) to the PHP using `RewriteRule (.*) hotel-detail.php?$1` and then parsing the query string inside PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost same issue. And I got the best method to get this done.
.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

url parse code

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = str_replace(".html", "", $url);
    $url = str_replace("-", "_", $url);
        //you could use rtrim(); but I had some trouble when the url had the "t" as the ending character.
    //$url = rtrim($url, '.html');
    $url = explode('/', $url);
```

By doing so you will get the url in $url array.

say mydomain.com/komet-india/Best-Indian-Hill-Stations-1/Delhis-Hotel

```
$url[0] = komet_india
$url[1] = Best_Indian_Hill_Stations_1
$url[2] = Delhis_Hotel
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rewrite rule like this...

```
RewriteRule komet-india/(.*)-(\d+)/(.*)$ hotel-detail.php?title=$1&id=$2&top=$3&hotel=4 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try change your rewrite rule to the one below. Tha should crea

```
Rewrite Rule (.*)-(\d+)/(.*)/? hotel-detail.php?title=$1&id=$2&top=$3&hotel=4 [nc]
```

Also im not sure if you need the komet-india there. But i dont know your localhost set up.